# apache2 через Tor proxy

Tags: php, apache, nginx, tor

Приветствую!

**Задача:** сделать сервер на котором расположен .onion домен полностью анонимным.

**Проблема:** Если пользователь выполнит код ниже, то он деанонимизирует сервер.

Сам код, которым тестировал:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', true);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
    try {
function curl_get_contents($url){
$page = "";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; YandexImageResizer/2.0)');
$page = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $page;
}
echo curl_get_contents("http://2ip.ru");
 } catch(Exception $e) {
     var_dump($e);
 }
?>
```

**Решение:** Перенаправлять все через Tor proxy. Но как это сделать?
Я пробовал ставить polipo, чтобы использовать tor-socks как http-proxy, но у меня ничего не вышло.

**Мои конфиги:**

**apache:**

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
    ServerName [удалено].onion
    #ProxyPass ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:8118/$1
    #ProxyPassReverse ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:8118/$1
    DocumentRoot /var/www/[удалено]/data/www/[удалено].onion
    ServerAdmin webmaster@[удалено].onion
    AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
    AssignUserID [удалено] [удалено]
    ErrorLog /dev/null 
    AccessLog /dev/null
    <FilesMatch "\.ph(p[3-5]?|tml)$">
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\.phps$">
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
    </FilesMatch>
    php_admin_value sendmail_path "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f webmaster@[удалено].onion"
    php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir "/var/www/[удалено]/data/mod-tmp"
    php_admin_value session.save_path "/var/www/[удалено]/data/mod-tmp"
    php_admin_value open_basedir "/var/www/[удалено]/data:."
    ServerAlias www.[удалено].onion
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</VirtualHost>
<Directory /var/www/[удалено]/data/www/[удалено].onion>
    Options -ExecCGI
    php_admin_flag engine on
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/[удалено]/data/www/[удалено].onion/phpmyadmin>
    Allow from all
    AuthName "Access limited"
    AuthType Basic
    AuthUserFile /var/www/[удалено]/data/etc/access.[удалено].onion.passwd
    Order allow,deny
    Require valid-user
</Directory>
```

**nginx:**

```
server {
    server_name [удалено].onion www.[удалено].onion;
    charset UTF-8;
    index index.html index.php;
    disable_symlinks if_not_owner from=$root_path;
    include /etc/nginx/vhosts-includes/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/vhosts-resources/[удалено].onion/*.conf;
    access_log off;
    error_log off;
    set $root_path /var/www/[удалено]/data/www/[удалено].onion;
    root $root_path;
    listen 127.0.0.1:80;
    gzip on;
    gzip_comp_level 5;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript;
    location / {
        location ~ [^/]\.ph(p\d*|tml)$ {
            try_files /does_not_exists @fallback;
        }
        location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|js|css|mp3|ogg|mpe?g|avi|zip|gz|bz2?|rar|swf)$ {
            expires max;
            try_files $uri $uri/ @fallback;
        }
        location / {
            try_files /does_not_exists @fallback;
        }
    }
    location @fallback {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:8080 /;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
    location /phpmyadmin/ {
        location ~ [^/]\.ph(p\d*|tml)$ {
            try_files /does_not_exists @fallback;
        }
        location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|js|css|mp3|ogg|mpe?g|avi|zip|gz|bz2?|rar|swf)$ {
            expires max;
            try_files $uri $uri/ @fallback;
        }
        location /phpmyadmin/ {
            try_files /does_not_exists @fallback;
        }
        auth_basic "Access limited";
        auth_basic_user_file /var/www/[удалено]/data/etc/access.[удалено].onion.passwd;
    }
}
```

**pilipo:**

```
proxyAddress = "0.0.0.0"  # Razreshit' podklyucheniya otovsyudu. YA v lokalke, tak chto pofig
proxyPort = 8118 # eto standartnyy port dlya Privoxy, u Polipo obychno 8123
allowedClients = 127.0.0.1, 192.168.1.0/24 # Otkuda prinimat' podklyucheniya
allowedPorts = 1-65535 # Porty po kotorym mozhno prinimat' / otdavat' soyedineniya
socksParentProxy = "127.0.0.1:9050" # TOR Roditel'skiy
socksProxyType=socks4a # Tip soks-proksi
diskCacheRoot = "/var/cache/polipo/" # Kuda keshirovat'
disableConfiguration = false # mozhno nastraivat' cherekh set', yesli ne strashno
disableVia = true # Ubezhdat'sya, chto zaprosy ne budut khodit' cherez proksi po krugu.
relaxTransparency = yes #
maxConnectionAge = 10m # Maksimal'noye vremya zhizni podklyucheniya
maxConnectionRequests = 100 # Maksimum zaprosov cherez odno podklyucheniya
serverMaxSlots = 16 # Maksimum parallel'nykh podklyucheniy k raznym serveram
serverSlots = 60 # Maksimum parallel'nykh podklyucheniy k odnomu serveru
tunnelAllowedPorts = 1-65535
daemonise=true # Ukhodit' v fon
logFile="/var/log/polipo/polipo.log" # kuda skladyvat' logi
dnsMaxTimeout=60 # yesli khost ne rezolvitsya za 60 sek, to nu yego k chertu.
dontCacheCookies = true # Ne nado keshirovat' kuki
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел одно решение, но оно пустит весь трафик сервера через прокси тора:

**Конфиг privoxy:**

```
forward-socks5 / localhost:9050 .
forward-socks4 / localhost:9050 .
forward-socks4a / localhost:9050 .
```

**Далее в консоли выполнить:** (после рестарта сервера, нужно выполнить заново)

```
export all_proxy="socks://localhost:9050/"
export http_proxy="http://localhost:8118/"
export https_proxy="http://localhost:8118/"
```